# LinkedIn API Partner program

Tags: linkedin-api

We have an app that wants to save users time when they create their profile. Ideally this would happen by tapping into LinkedIn's API and get the work experience and education background.We heard the LinkedIn partner program might offer that.

Anyone out there who has done so?
What information does LinkedIn allow partners to get?
What is the annual cost to sign up?